# php curl how not to use the system hosts file for name resolution?

Tags: php, curl

Because of security reasons,the system limit the curl destination domains.For example ,a.xxxx.com is in the collection of safe domains.But the ip address of this domain is not a safe domain.That leads:

```
$ch = curl_init('http:// 172.16.139.216:81'); //is fobbiden

$ch = curl_init('http:// a.xxxx.com:81'); //is ok
```

Now i want a domain `"a.xxxx.com"` pointing to other IP address. But i do not have the root permission of the machine,i can't modify `/etc/hosts`. So i wanna to do this in the php script,
is there any way?

Thx very much.

Comment: So you want to make `a.xxxx.com` point to the forbidden `172.16.139.216`? That's hardly going to be possible without root access (or access to xxxx.com's A records) - otherwise, the security provision of blocking specific IPs would be pointless, no?

Comment: No; it is not possible.

Comment: `"a.xxxx.com"` point to `"172.16.139.216"` now.But i can only use `"a.xxxx.com"` for requesting because ip addresses are not in the collection of safe domains and i must use `"a.xxxx.com"` to satisfy the security check. i want it pointed to another ip address.

Comment: Then talk to your admin who is responsible for those security measures.